# Client Accessing SQL Server Directly

Tags: sql-server

Q: Is it bad practice to have a client application communicate directly with SQL Server via port 1433? i.e. iOS device with application which has direct access to SQL Server via port 1433. I'm assuming yes and it should be via a web-service (SOAP,REST) , application server...

Comment: In many cases this is a non-issue because you'll find that clients (especially mobile ones) will be firewalled and unable to connect to your server in any case, either because your on-premise firewall configuration doesn't allow it or because the client network doesn't. Even where it's possible from a network point of view the hassle of securing the connections, isolating data and keeping interfaces fast and stable across versions typically negate the benefit of not having an additional layer.

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert, It is a bad idea to have any external client communicate with an internal server. If you want to be PCI-compliant (to take credit card payments), then the PCI documentation explicitly states that no external client can have direct contact with an internal server (because you would have to open ports on your firewall to pass the traffic which, in turn, increases your attack surface.) It is better to have some kind intermediate server in a demilitarized zone such as an API server or a reverse proxy.

Comment: Even if you ignore the security issues of providing access to your SQL Server over the open internet, it's a horrible idea from a performance point of view as well. The protocol used (MS-TDS) is extremely chatty because it was designed for use on LAN connections and slows down considerably as latency increases, which will happen over WAN connections and especially mobile data networks (which use tech like time division multiplexing and dynamic spectrum sharing). Data transfers would be much better serviced by protocols designed for general internet use such as web services over HTTP 1/2/3.